# How to wake up a sleeping monitor to display an alert using python

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter to create a python gui for the first time. Using broad strokes, its purpose is to alert me about something that occurs on another machine by way of receiving a tcp packet. So, this program runs and waits for a packet, and then pops up an alert message on the monitor. When the program starts, the single screen (g = tkinter.Tk() ) is created as the popup alert (with a dismiss button). It is then immediately minimized using the g.iconify() . When the packet is received, the screen pops up using the g.deiconify() .

Works for me.

However, after (in my case) 15 minutes of idleness, the monitor goes to sleep. The g.deiconify() works but the monitor doesn't "wake up". Its windows 10 if that matters.

I've used a program called caffiene64 in the past which stops my monitor from going to sleep when longer downloads or some such things are occuring. As i understand, it sends a keyup on function key 15 every minute thus preventing the monitor from sleeping.

Is there anything i can do in python to do the same sort of thing so that when the screen is deiconified on a sleeping monitor, the monitor wakes up? If i'm truly not around, i'm fine with the monitor going blank again in 15 minutes after waking up, but if i'm sitting at my desk or nearby, i'd like to be able to notice the alert.

I've also tried g.attributes('-topmost',True) and g.focus_force() but neither of those wake up the monitor either.

Comment: You need to specify a specific operating system here; answers will be different between MacOS, Windows, Linux-running-X11, and Linux-running-Wayland.

Comment: i'm new to stack so i assume you meant adding a windows tag since i did mention windows 10 in the original post. i have now added the tag. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

JRiggles' answer didn't do exactly what i wanted but it did send me down a different rabbit-hole using a slight mouse movement to wake up the monitor. Frankly, i did not expect this to work, but it seems to:

```
from ctypes import windll
 
def wakeUpMonitor():
 
    """ Move the mouse one unit to the right to wake up the monitor
    in case it's sleeping.
    """
    MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x0000 # coordinates supplied are relative
    MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE     = 0x0001 # this is a mouse movement
    MOUSE_DX             = 1 # minimum movement going right in the x-axis
    MOUSE_DY             = 0 # no movement in the y-axis
    MOUSE_DWDATA         = 0 # should be 0 for a mouse movement
 
    windll.user32.mouse_event(
        (MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE),
        MOUSE_DX,
        MOUSE_DY,
        MOUSE_DWDATA
    )
```

calling

```
wakeUpMonitor()
```

does do what i wanted.  This is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) to the documentation which got me here.

If the monitor is not asleep, the resulting mouse movement on the screen is not really felt. I suppose a perfect solution might be first checking if the screen is in fact asleep. I haven't figured out that part yet.

Instead of the subroutine, one could also just add:

```
windll.user32.mouse_event(1,1,0,0)
```

where needed.

Comment: My experience has been that when the system goes to sleep, it requires a login when it wakes up.  How did you get around that?

Comment: correct, but this was just about getting the monitor to wake up (maybe power up would have been a better phrase). the system itself has not gone to sleep. just the monitor has turned off.

Comment: @MarkRansom There is a setting in windows for login options like that. Go to Windows Settings -> Accounts -> Sign-in options - then in Additional settings you can set whether Windows should require you to sign in after sleep or not.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this method in the past to keep the computer in question from sleeping:

```
from ctypes import WinDLL

...  # your code here...

def prevent_sleep(prevent_sleep: bool = False) -> None:
    """Set system sleep behavior to keep the system awake and screen on"""
    # thread execution flags for enabling/disabling system sleep
    ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x0001  # keep system awake
    ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x0002  # keep display awake
    ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x8000_0000  # see MSDN SetThreadExecutionState docs
    kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
    if prevent_sleep:  # prevent system sleep
        kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(  # set to literal: 0x8000_0003
            (ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED)
        )
    else:  # allow system sleep
        kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS)
```

Then all you need to do in order to keep the system awake is call

```
prevent_sleep(True)
```

You should also call `prevent_sleep(False)` at app exit to ensure your system goes back to the "normal" sleep behavior.

[Here's a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) to the documentation for the Windows `SetThreadExecutionState` function if you're curious about the particulars.

Comment: this works well to keep the monitor on during the entire length of the program run but i can't get it to "wake up" a monitor by calling prevent_sleep(True) once i receive the trigger. the monitor stays dark.

Comment: Since your program is running minimized, the idea would be to have it call `prevent_sleep(True)` when it starts up. But yeah, the catch there is that your computer will no longer sleep so long as that app is running. This doesn’t wake from sleep, it prevents sleep altogether - admittedly an imperfect solution.